# How to add White color to web view Background

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, webview

I have a web view to show the pdf. When it displaying the pdf it's not taking full area it's not the issues with me, but the background color of it shows a kind of dark color background I need to remove that dark color to white how to do this in xamarin forms

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use Google doc viewer to load the remote pdf files? If so, the extra border can't be removed as it is controlled by Google. I didn't find any api to change that appearance. But you can change the embedded style:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.NewElement != null)
    {
        var customWebView = Element as CustomWebView;
        Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
        Control.LoadUrl("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + customWebView.Uri);
    }
}
```

It shows a light gray border when we set the embedded to true.

You have to create a custom control on Forms for consuming the custom renderer above:

```
public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Uri",
            returnType: typeof(string),
            declaringType: typeof(CustomWebView),
            defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

At last, use it in XAML:

```
<StackLayout>
    <local:CustomWebView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Uri="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" />
</StackLayout>
```

**Update:**

It can scroll if pdf has couples of pages:

[image]

Comment: customWebView.Uri what should be the format of this it does not preview my item it says No Preview available

Comment: Yes, it solves the colour problem but it cannot scroll and it has some field I do not want that because I have a custom button that would show after it touches webview. Can override those issues

Comment: @C_Subash It scrolls fine on my side, please see my screenshot. What part don't you want?

Comment: after the scroll it has a black box with page no and zoom in/out I want to remove that

Comment: @C_Subash Unfortunately, this is a Google Doc View, we can't customize it as what we want. We have to accept the style with embedded property to true or false.